# How can I combine multiple videos into a single composite side-by-side?

Tags: video, software-rec, editing

I would like to combine three (possibly more) video sequences into a composite video, where the sequences are running side-by-side as show below. I do not need to have overlapping pictures although that capability would be desirable)

Can anyone recommend a tool for this?

[image: the picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Non-Linear Video Editor:

- Adobe Premiere
- Avidemux
- Final Cut

If you're on a Linux Machine there's also:

- Kino
- Cinelerra

Comment: do you mean "Avidemux" not "Adivemux"?

Comment: I download Avidemux; it seems like a useful tool but I still can't see how to compose multiple videos as I asked in the question above

Comment: Wrong spelling sorry quack.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle some scripting, try [AviSynth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avisynth2/).

AviSynth outputs .avi video, which can be encoded by your favourite encoder. eg. VirtualDub.

Below is sample script which takes a single file and chops it up into four panels, which are then surrounded by blue margins.
It can just as easily handle four different video sources.
AviSynth is a very powerful tool, but scripting does not suit everyone.

```
#BEGIN----------
inVid=AviSource("myVides.avi")
Mg=8    # Margin:               # must be a multiple of 4
hM=Mg/2 # half Margin           # must be an even number 
pane1H=((inVid.height/8)/2)*2   # round it to an even number
pane1W=((inVid.width   )/2)*2   # round it to an even number
pane2H=((inVid.height/2)/2)*2   # round it to an even number
pane2W=((inVid.width /3)/2)*2   # round it to an even number
pane3H=pane2H
pane3W=pane1W-pane2W
pane4H=((inVid.height-pane2H-pane1H)/2)*2 # round it to an even number
pane4W=pane1W
####   Crop( clip  ,Left      ,Top           ,-Right     ,-Bottom        ).AddBorders( L  ,T  ,R  ,B  ,Colour  ) 
pane1 =Crop( inVid ,0         ,0             ,-0         ,-pane2H-pane4H ).AddBorders( Mg ,Mg ,Mg ,hM ,$00ffff )
pane2 =Crop( inVid ,0         ,pane1H        ,-pane3W-hM ,-pane4H        ).AddBorders( Mg ,hM ,hM ,hM ,$00ffff )
pane3 =Crop( inVid ,pane2W+hM ,pane1H        ,-0         ,-pane4H        ).AddBorders( hM ,hM ,Mg ,hM ,$00ffff )
pane4 =Crop( inVid ,0         ,pane1H+pane3H ,-0         ,-0             ).AddBorders( Mg ,hM ,Mg ,Mg ,$00ffff )
row1=pane1
row2=StackHorizontal(pane2, pane3)
row3=pane4
out=StackVertical(row1, StackVertical(row2, row3))
return out
#END----------
```